# Renaming repository folder causes "git status failed with code 128 this operation must be run in a work tree"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have renamed my local Git repository folder through file system (Windows File Explorer) and now Git status (when inspecting repository through SourceTree) fails every time with

> git status failed with code 128 this operation must be run in a work tree

Basically I only changed outside folder name, and I haven't touched inner repository structure.

```
OldRepoName    
│   .gitattributes
│   .gitignore
│   README.md
│   │   ...
│   
└───.git
│   │   config
│   │   ...
│   
└─── ...


NewRepoName    
│   .gitattributes
│   .gitignore
│   README.md
│   │   ...
│   
└───.git
│   │   config
│   │   ...
│   
└─── ...
```

All searches about "this operation must be run in a work tree" error I could find are dealing with bare repositories that never had work tree structure. This repository was not bare repository.

How do I fix the repo, without cloning it again from the remote?

---

Note: As a Mercurial user, I am quite used to renaming the repository folders,  without any negative consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repository contains configuration file which uses absolute path to the work tree. Fixing that path to point to new, renamed, folder fixes the repository.

1. Open `.git/config` file in text editor
2. locate `worktree` entry under `[core]` configuration
3. update absolute repo path to new one and save changes

from (this is Windows example, but same principle applies to other OS)

```
worktree = C:/OldPath/OldRepoName
```

to

```
worktree = C:/NewPath/NewRepoName
```

Comment: Answer is not based on info in question. Use of `core.worktree` highly questionable.

Comment: @matt What do you mean that answer is not based on info in question? I renamed (in Windows Explorer) local folder containing the whole repository, which broke it and updating path in core.worktree fixed the problem. All other searches about same error, were pointing to issues with bare repository - which this one was not and nothing was changed beyond renaming local folder.

Comment: I think he means that your question does not suggest that you’re using worktrees and - given that they’re not in common use - the answer is quite a surprise.  I agree; other people with this question would not be able to rely on the answer unless they, too, used worktrees.  Thus that information is a critical part of the question that has been omitted.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks for the clarification. I am rather dumb Git user, and I am using it almost exclusively though GUI clients (mostly SourceTree) So I never even knew there is a thing called "worktree" until is messed up my repo :) and I didn't think that mentioning GUI client was relevant.